# Auto Login User using Phone Number in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to create a chat app. I am using Phone Authentication to register users. I have 5 activities

- SplashScreen
- Register
- VerifyOTP
- TakeUserInfo
- Chat

So, what I want is that if User has already registered he should be auto-login after Splash Screen?

How can I do that ??
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Firebase doesn't logs out any user unless the user clicks any log out button. SO when you restart the app, the user will automatically get diverted to main activity. You just have to add an if-else statement.

Comment: Hi @Harsh Ashra , if my answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try that; in `onStart()` method in your Splash Screen, you can check whether the user is logged in or not. you can do something like that

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
    // User is signed in, go to home activity/fragment.
} else {
    // No user is signed in, go to signin acitvity/fragment.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your `LoginActivity`:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FirebaseUser userToBeLoggedIn = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    if (userToBeloggedIn != null) {
        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class))
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Login/Register", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();     
    }
}
```

Firebase doesn't logs out any user. User must logout by himself.

Now if the user is already logged in, it will proceed else it will prompt user to Login or Register.